# CLI Commands to a running process

Tags: c++, linux

1. How does GDB achieves the feat of attaching itself to a running procesS?
2. I need a similar capability, where i can issue CLI commands to a running process. For example, i can query the process internal state such as show total_messages_processed? How can  i build support for issuing commands to a running process under linux?
3. Is there a library that can provide CLI communication abilities to a running process and can be extended for custom commands?

The process itself is written in c++

Comment: What kind of process is it? Is is a long-running server process?

Answer (score 3):

GDB doesn't use the CLI to communicate with its debugee; it uses the [`ptrace`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ptrace) system call / API.

CLI means "command-line interface". The simplest form of communication between processes is `stdin` / `stdout`. This is achieved through pipes.  For example:

```
ps -ef | grep 'httpd'
```

The standard output of `ps` (which will be a process listing) is connected to the standard input of `grep`, who will process that process listing output line-by-line.

Are you writing both programs, or you want to communicate with an already-existing process? I have no idea what "show total_messages_processed" means without context.

---

If you simply want the program to communicate some status, a good approach is that which `dd` takes: Sending the process the `SIGUSR1` signal causes it to dump out its current stats to `stderr` and continue processing:

```
$ dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null&
[1] 19716
$ pid=$!
$ kill -usr1 $pid
$ 10838746+0 records in
10838746+0 records out
5549437952 bytes (5.5 GB) copied, 9.8995 s, 561 MB/s
```

Comment: However, the pipe method can't be used with a process that's already running, it has to be set up when creating the process.

Comment: both programs are under my control and show total_messages_processed  was a simple example of a command that can be issued to a running process and it is asking the process to spit out the number of messages it processed during its uptime

Comment: Then as Basile suggested below, I would recommend using a local unix (`AF_UNIX`) socket to communicate between them.

Answer (score 2):

Did you consider using [AF_UNIX](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/unix.7.html) sockets in your process? or [D-bus](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/dbus)? or make it an HTTP server (e.g. using [libonion](http://coralbits.com/staticc/libonion/html/) or [libmicrohttpd](http://www.gnu.org/software/libmicrohttpd/)), perhaps for [SOAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP), or [RCP/XDR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Network_Computing_Remote_Procedure_Call)

Read some books on [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/), or [Advanced Unix Programming](http://basepath.com/aup/); you surely want to use (perhaps indirectly) some multiplexing syscall like [poll(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/poll.2.html) perhaps above some event libary like [libev](http://software.schmorp.de/pkg/libev.html). Maybe you want to dedicate a thread for that.

We cannot tell more without knowing what kind of process are you thinking of. You may have to redesign some part of it. If the process is some traditional compute-intensive thing it is not the same as a SMTP server process. In particular, if you have some event loop in the process, use & extend it for monitoring purposes. If you don't have any event loop (e.g. in a traditional number crunching "batch" application) you may need to add one.

Answer (score 0):

In this case I'd suggest 'fork', which splits the currently running process into two. The parent process would read stdin, process the commands and be able to handle all memory that is shared between the two processes. One could theoretically even skip advanced forms of *interprocess communication*: locks, mutexes, semaphores, signals, sockets or pipes -- but be prepared that the *child* process has not necessarily written it's state to memory but keeps it in registers.

At fork Operating System makes a copy of the process local variables, after which each process have their own internal state -- thus the easiest method for passing data would be to allocate "shared memory".

One can also write a signal handler to the child process, that goes to *sleep/wait state* and exits only on another signal -- in that way one can have more time to inspect the child processes internal state. The main rationale for this kind of approach is that one doesn't have to make the process under debugging aware of being debugged: the parent and child processes share the same code base and it's enough for the parent process to implement necessary output methods (formatting to screen?) and serializing the data etc.

Comment: I am not at all sure that `fork` is relevant for the original poster.

Comment: Well, memory can be shared between any other processes as well, but I just consider fork one of the easiest methods to share the process_id and to make sure the attached process is running. It's a couple of files and 50 lines more compact solution than e.g. client server model using sockets.

Comment: The original poster have a long-running process and want to be able to query some internal application state. I don't understand how `fork` is relevant....